# How to repair dry sack with delaminated TPU

Tags: gear, repairs, waterproofing, rain-gear

How can I re-apply a [PolyUrethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polyurethane_applications#Textiles) (PU or TPU) lining on a (formerly) waterproof fabric whose original lining has delaminated?

My trusty laundry bag's waterproof lining has delaminated such that it now leaks water out of the bottom faster than it fills with water from the faucet.

The fabric of the bag is made of (green) nylon, which is intact. Only the inner lining of (white) TPU is wearing away, causing the bag to leak. See photos below.

| [image: photo of the outside of a green dry bag] | [image: photo of the white inside of the dry bag with the TPU has worn away in some places] |
| --- | --- |
| This 4-year-old, 20L Sea To Summit "Lightweight Dry Sack" is made out of 70D nylon. The nylon material is intact and has held-up well to years of use | The inside of the same dry bag has a white TPU coating with a 10,000mm hydrostatic head. This waterproof lining has delaminated from the nylon, making the dry bag no longer waterproof. |

I figure if I could somehow strip the TPU off the nylon and re-apply a waterproof PU layer, then the bag should be waterproof again. How can I do this? Is there any other way to repair this bag so that it's waterproof again?

Comment: See also https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29003/durable-waterproof-dry-bags

Comment: See also https://web.archive.org/web/20170219113329/https://www.whitemountain.com.au/backpack-construction/delaminating.html

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to coat a nylon fabric with polyurethane varnish that's sold in every hardware store (that's intended for use on sealing wood) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish#Polyurethane

Comment: I'd say your drybag has exhausted it's useful lifespan. Time to buy a new one. It'll prob be more expensive to repair than to replace. And from a sustainability POV probably worse for the environment with whatever chemicals you'll need to buy to strip and replace the PU coating.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield it's almost certainly not flexible enough when cured, and would crack

Comment: @noah I'm ok to buy a new dry bag, but not ok to buy one that will have this same problem. I don't mind paying more for something that lasts longer. Do you have any recommendations on a dry bag that is made from a waterproof material (as opposed to one that's layered with a waterproof lining (that can delaminate)?

Comment: anything that's not laminated should last longer (so, silnylon or PU-poly or something of the sort), but pay attention to the seam-sealing (possibly do it yourself with sealant), as tape made come off eventually - although it's easier to fix than the delamination you're seeing. As a side note, this sort of bag is not meant to be carrying water.

Comment: @njzk2 they're not laminated, but they're still coated, and the coatings can wear (though they're more repairable than this)

Comment: @MichaelAltfield, if you want a sturdier option then go for the heavy-duty sacks for kayaking and other water sports. I use some for 10+ years and they look like the day I bought them. They will however be significantly heavier and bulkier than the light-weight option you have (I use the same ones for trekking btw). Yet another alternative is to go for proper plastic barrels with air-tight lids. They can take a lot of abuse, but will of course be very bulky and heavy.

Comment: @fgysin can you supply any more technical information about the sacks that you have experience lasting 10+ years? What material are they made of? What denier? Are they lined with anything, if so what's the lining made of? This information will help me and others know exactly what to look for.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield The material is similar to the water-proof tarpaulins used on large trucks. That stuff is almost indestructible: it is not coated only on the inside, but instead the material is a composite of fabric and PVC, with the PVC laminated to both sides. You should find these in any large outdoor / water sports store (at least that is the case here in Switzerland). No idea about the denier, but I guess that is not the important factor, but rather the thickness of the PVC laminates. The stuff is heavy, a 40l bag could weigh 1kg or thereabouts... Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @fgysin thanks :) is the fabric nylon, polyester, or something else?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield the ones only where I found specs say that the main fabric was 100% PVC (example in German: https://www.decathlon.de/p/wasserfeste-tasche-40-l/_/R-p-325070?mc=8584877&c=GRÜN_KHAKI)

Answer (score 5):

Small areas of damage can be repaired with tape (for example Tenacious Tape), but even with a very robust tape this is temporary in practice.  Once the delamination starts it will continue.  I repaired a few leaky, obviously damaged patches on my drysuit, but within a few months it became clear that large areas had become porous.

In the field, I'd use duct tape (I have some in my bike tool kit and kayaking emergency bag; I often grab the latter for day hikes). Once you get home, it's only fit to be used as a splash-resistant stuff sack